I deployed WAR on Tomcat but I can't access my controller?
I made a small jakarta ee project, created the war, copied the war file to my tomcat's webapps folder, started it but it does not access my controller method, it throws 404:
package com.example.config;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class AppConfig extends Application {
}

package com.example.controller;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class BaseController {

    @GET
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}


mvn compile war:war --> rename the war file to myapp.war --> copy myapp.war to tomcat /webapps --> run the tomcat with startup.bat --> open localhost:8080
I can see that it is running

But if I try to access http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/hello

I wonder what am I missing?

Have you checked the logfile? What's it's content?

It is important to add the relevant implementation of jersey. Because Tomcat 10.1 does not provide a complete implementation of Jakarta EE 10.
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>myapp project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Project Tree
myapp
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    ├── config
                    │   └── AppConfig.java
                    └── controller
                        └── BaseController.java

Build
mvn clean package

Put war file into Tomcat
myapp.war
Test
curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/hello


Tomcat version: apache-tomcat-10.1.28
JDK version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.11


A complete answer! Excellent!

Jakarta EE
Of the dozens of specifications defined in Jakarta EE, Tomcat supports only four: Jakarta Servlet, Jakarta Pages (formerly Jakarta Server Pages JSP), Jakarta Expression Language, and Jakarta Authentication.
Notice that the Jakarta RESTful Web Services technology that you want to use is not among that list of technologies supported by Tomcat.
If you want to use additional Jakarta EE technologies, I suggest moving from Tomcat to another app server product that does support your choice of technologies.
Note that Jakarta EE defines a Jakarta EE Web Profile which is a subset of some of the many Jakarta EE technologies. Your desired  Jakarta RESTful Web Services is among that subset. So you can use any app server product that complies with that profile, or with its superset the “full” Jakarta EE platform. Any compliant app server will come bundled with both the interfaces and the implementations for all Jakarta EE technologies listed in the profile, including your desired Jakarta RESTful Web Services.
Such app server products include Glassfish & Payara, WildFly & JBoss, Open Liberty & IBM WebSphere, and more.
In particular you may be interested in TomEE which is built on top of Tomcat. (Caveat: TomEE seems to not yet be updated for Jakarta EE 10 or 11, supporting only Jakarta EE 9.1.)

A well-researched answer!

That said, these days it may be simpler if there is no external requirements just to write a small spring boot application.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not everyone is a fan of Spring.

@BasilBourque Well, there are very few things that everyone are fans of.  Given you like to give very thorough answers, alternate pointers may be relevant too for newcomers to the game.
